# Entity Framework - Update-database Command Prompting for ConnectionProviderName

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to run Update-Database with a provided connection string. For my tests, I added the  `-Script` flag such to be non-destructive

It appears as though parameter ConnectionProviderName is required in the connection string but simply adding it causes this error:

```
Keyword not supported: 'ConnectionProviderName'
```

I am having trouble passing in the parameter "ConnectionProviderName"

I can run the command in 2 steps as seen below but I would rather do the command in 1 step.

```
   PM> update-database -ConnectionString 'data source=10.10.10.20;initial  catalog=MyDatabase;user id=db_user;password=1234;'  -Script
```

Returns the following request for more info, which I then need to provide:

```
cmdlet Update-Database at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ConnectionProviderName: System.Data.SqlClient
```

After I provide the ConnectionProviderName, the command runs fine.

How can I do this in 1 command?

Thanks

Comment: Did you specify the connectionstring in your config file? Are there 0, 1 or N connections in there? Can you show them?

Comment: I think the issue was that ConnectionProviderName must be it's own param and cannot be included in the connection string, for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are separate arguments. When you put these in a configuration file (which I would recommend), you use

```
<add name="myConnection"
    connectionString="data source=10.10.10.20;initial  catalog=MyDatabase;user id=db_user;password=1234;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If you only have one connection string in your config file then you can simply call `update-database`. If you have multiple however, you have to call it with `update-database -ConnectionStringName "myConnection"` to distinguish between each connection.

If you really want to specify it in every call then you just specify both arguments.

Answer (score 9):

The param ConnectionProviderName cannot be specified in the connection string; it must be it's own param, apparently, because the following works

```
update-database -ConnectionString 'data source=10.10.10.20;initial  catalog=MyDatabase;user id=db_user;password=1234;'  -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient  -Script
```